# Prove that the second derivative has a zero

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

my question is: Can I use Rolle's theorem to prove that the second derivative has a zero?

Consider a Real function of Real variable defined by $f(x)=(x+1)\cdot e^{x^2}$. 
Prove that the second derivative has a root.

So I did the $f ' (x)$.

$f ' (x) = e^{x^2}(2x^2 + 2x + 1)$

The $f ' (x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

$f ' (x)$ is differentiable.

$f ''(x) = (4x^3+4x^2+6x+2)\cdot e^{x^2}$

and $f ' (- \infty) = f ' (+\infty)$

So for the Rolle Theorem there is a point $c$ that belongs at $(- \infty, + \infty)$ such that $f ''(c) = 0$

is this correct?

Comment: Do you have to use Rolle's theorem? – What can you say about zeros of $4x^3+4x^2+6x+2$?

Comment: To continue on Martin's comment, $e^{x^2}$ has no roots, and the polynomial has no positive roots for obvious reasons. Note that as $x\to-\infty$, $f''(x)\to-\infty$. So, there does exist a root that is negative.

Comment: Your application of Rolle's Theorem requires that we use extended real numbers (i.e. we add $\pm\infty$ to $\mathbb{R}$), which is rather unusual. The hypothesis $g(a)=g(b)$ in Rolle's Theorem usually means that $a$ and $b$ are (finite) real numbers. If you allow this extended version of Rolle's Theorem, then I guess your proof is ok. However, it's much simpler to use the fact that a cubic always has a real zero.